# Routing in Angular 2 with ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, routes, angular2-routing

I added to an existing MVC (aspnet core) application some interfaces that use Angular2 for the front end.

but im having an issue, when you access by url or refresh 
instead of loading the component that corresponds load the home component ignoring the route.

Ex:
the app has 2 components, holaComponent, chauComponent.

if i type in url bar

> localhost/Admin.mvc/Angular

land in localhost/Admin.mvc/Angular/Hola. Thats Perfect! Hola is my "home" component.

if i type

> localhost/Admin.mvc/Angular/Chau

land in localhost/Admin.mvc/Angular/Chau/Hola. Load the Hola component instead of Chau component.

if i type

> localhost/Admin.mvc/Angular/Hola

land in localhost/Admin.mvc/Angular/Hola/Hola.

some things for keep in mind:

- Routes using the 'routerLink=""' work fine. the problem  only appears
  when you access by url or refresh.
- Angular2 app is boostrap in a view (view name: Angular).
- Admin.mvc is a controller, using also for non angular views.

routeConfig.cs file:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Homepage",
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Controller",
            url: "{controller}",
            defaults: new { action = "Index" }                             
             );



        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            ,
              constraints: new
              {
                  serverRoute = new ServerRouteConstraint(url =>
                  {
                      return !url.PathAndQuery.StartsWith("/Admin.mvc/Angular",
                          StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                  })
              }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
       name: "spa-fallback",
       url: "Admin.mvc/Angular/{*pathInfo}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Angular"});

    }
```

my angular Routing Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { FlekzComponent } from './ng-flekz.component';
import { HolaComponent } from './ng-flekz-hola.component';
import { ChauComponent } from './ng-flekz-chau.component';

const routes: Routes = [    
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'hola', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'hola', component: HolaComponent },
    { path: 'chau', component: ChauComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class FlekzRoutingModule { }
```

-sorry for the bad english, is not my native lenguage.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's acceptable for you but if you're OK with having a hash in URL you could import like so: `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})`. Then you'll have the same base URL for the app (in your case it's `Admin.mvc/Angular`) and rest of the app will be routed as such:

- Admin.mvc/Angular/#/hola -> HolaComponent
- Admin.mvc/Angular/#/chau -> ChauComponent

Check if you'll need to update `base` href to whatever path you'll be using.

Comment: im okay with this, but dont work either. 
Admin.mvc/Angular -> Admin.mvc/Angular#/hola

the slash before the hash is missing

my base href:
<base href="~Admin.mvc/Angular">

Comment: The final character in base href has to be slash.

Comment: Check developer tools network tab to see where assets are loaded from and based on that adjust your base path. Most likely you will see 404's for files and from there you will get what basepath value should be.